# Тонкости Espresso

Tags: java, android, espresso

Пробую писать на espresso with cucumber.
И в одном из примеров наткнулся на такую строчку:

```
@Given("^I've launched \"([^\"]*)\"$") public void I_ve_launched_(String activityClassName)
```

Интересно в роли чего эти символы?

```
\"([^\"]*)\"$
```

Полный код метода:

```
  @Given("^I've launched \"([^\"]*)\"$") public void I_ve_launched_(String activityClassName)
  throws Throwable {
String targetPackage = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getPackageName();
Class<? extends Activity> activityClass =
    (Class<? extends Activity>) Class.forName(activityClassName);

currentActivity = launchActivity(targetPackage, activityClass, null);


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это регулярное выражение - regexp. Данное означает - любое количество (ноль тоже подходит) любых символов кроме " заключенные в кавычки ("), закрывающая кавычка должна быть последним символом. Эти символы (кроме кавычек) потом будут переданы в качестве параметра в метод.

Comment: а зачем мы это делаем? в конкретном случае...

Comment: @Inkognito так работает Cucmber. Поищите у себя в проект файлы .feature и в них должны быть строчки начинающиеся с Given  I've launched "..."

Comment: Да, есть. То есть это для них ограничение?

Comment: какое ограничение? почитайте про Cucumber и все станет понятно https://habrahabr.ru/post/62958/